# Nginx config to redirect to $URI

Tags: nginx, configuration

I have a problem with nginx. If you call "example.com" or "example.example.com", nginx redirects it to "www.example.com" like I want without a problem. But it doesn't redirect if I enter an URI like this : "example.com/doesnt-redirect". It won't add the "www." part and therefore, I get a 404 from my Blog-Site. My config is :

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com *.example.com;

    if ($http_host != "www.example.com") {
        return  301 http://www.example.com$request_uri;
    }

    root /home/ghost/;
    index index.html;

}
```

Comment: and plus, you should change root /home/ghost/; as root /home/ghost;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `server_name .example.com;` instead.

From nginx's [server names](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#wildcard_names) documentation :

> A special wildcard name in the form “.example.org” can be used to match both the exact name “example.org” and the wildcard name “*.example.org”.

Note that `www.example.com` can be removed as the wildcard form will match it anyway.