# subdomain redirects not working for https

Tags: nginx

I am trying to make all `subdomain.example.com` requests be redirected to `example.com`. Using nginx file in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`:

```
server {
        server_name ~^(?<sub>.+)\.example\.com$;
        rewrite ^ $scheme://example.com$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

It works perfectly for HTTP requests. So it redirects `http://anySubDomain.example.com` to `http://example.com`
but not working for https:

`https://mySubDomain.example.com` returns 200 ok without redirects.

So how to redirect `https://anySubdomain.example.com` to `https://example.com`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nginx config to redirect to $URI](https://serverfault.com/questions/663091/nginx-config-to-redirect-to-uri)

Comment: The `server` block in your question only handles `http` connections.

Answer (score 0):

The following nginx file does what I want:

```
server {
        listen 443;
        listen 80;
        server_name ~^(?<sub>.+)\.example\.com$;
        rewrite ^ $scheme://example.com$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

It redirects `https://anySubdomain.example.com` to `https://example.com` and `http://anySubdomain.example.com` to `http://example.com`